# Adding buttons on runtime to a Layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, runtime

I'm working on an Android project and I need to add buttons to a Layout on runtime. So, this is the layout xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/layout">

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the Activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.TableLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class PluginsActivity extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.plugins);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        Button butt = new Button(this);
        Button butt2 = new Button(this);
        butt.setText("lol");
        butt2.setText("lol2");
        butt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        butt2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        layout.addView(butt);
        layout.addView(butt2);

    }

}
```

Now, the problem is that when i start the activity, the button 1 "covers" the button 2. In fact if I use LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) both the buttons are shown. Is there a way to add a "new line" on the LinearLayout? The screen should be like this:

---

|****************Button1*********************|

---

|****************Button2*********************|

---

Thanks.

Comment: Please also change your `import android.widget.TableLayout.LayoutParams;` to `import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the oritentation vertical of your LinearLayout in the layout file

```
< LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
```

and

```
butt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
butt2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: is it advisable to add widget at runtime ?

Answer (score 1):

activity_main.xml

---

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

</LinearLayout>
```

// mention the android:orientation="vertical"

.... this was the main problem....make it vertical  and will work

Answer (score 0):

```
Activity_Main.java
____________________________________________________________________________

package com.example.dynamic;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);

        Button b1 = new Button(this);
        b1.setText("A");

        Button b2 = new Button(this);
        b2.setText("B");

        Button b3 = new Button(this);
        b3.setText("C");

        Button b4 = new Button(this);
        b4.setText("D");

        Button b5 = new Button(this);
        b5.setText("E");

        Button b6 = new Button(this);
        b6.setText("F");

        layout.addView(b1);
        layout.addView(b2);
        layout.addView(b3);
        layout.addView(b4);
        layout.addView(b5);
        layout.addView(b6);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```